# How to create a TopoJSON geomap using Altair library for Python?

Tags: python, topojson, jupyter-lab, altair, geomap

I am trying to create a geomap of a state using Altair package for Python. I will then plot let's say dots representing some event at a location specified by its latitude & longitude. I follow the Altair's example gallery [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airports_count.html). The TopoJSON file is located in the GitHub repository [deldersveld/topojson](https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/us-states/MI-26-michigan-counties.json). However, I can't get it to draw the map of Michigan. Is this file missing something? Anyone who can help me?

Environment:

- Windows 10
- python 3
- jupyter-lab 1.0.0a3
- altair 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import altair as alt

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/us-states/MI-26-michigan-counties.json"

source = alt.topo_feature(url, "cb_2015_michigan_county_20m")

alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape().encode(
    tooltip='properties.NAME:N'
)
```

[image]

The key is to look in the `"objects"` and `"properties"` entries of the TopoJSON file to figure out what to use for features and encodings.

Comment: I get it. I had the same code but I was providing the normal link. I had to provide the "raw" link to github. I don't know how to define this. Basically, I was giving: "https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/us-states/MI-26-michigan-counties.json" instead of "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson..."